# Bound for the cardinality of maximal $r$-separable subsets contained in a ball of radius $R$ in $\mathbb R^d$

Tags: reference-request, mg.metric-geometry, geometric-measure-theory, packing-and-covering

Let $B$ be a closed ball in $\mathbb R^d$ of radius $R$ and let $N=N_R(r)$ denote the maximal cardinality of the $r$-separated sets (meaning any two points in this set have distance at least $r$) that can be contained in $B$.

If $r>2R$ then $N_R(r)=1$.

If $r\le 2R$, I expect $N$ can be bounded by something like $C(\frac{2R}{r})^{d+\delta}$ where $C,\delta$ are absolute constants (I may be wrong here. Let me know the correct form).

I wonder what are naive/classical/latest results on this estimation.

Comment: Hint: compare volumes. This is naive/classical and not so bad. You get the bound $(\frac{2R}{r}+1)^d$.

Comment: The key observation is that balls of radius $r/2$ centered in the separated set cannot intersect and have to lie completely in a ball of radius $R+r/2$. Conversely any such balls of radius $r/2$ in $B_{R+r/2}$ have a center in $B_R$ and if they do not intersect their centers have distance at least $r$, so your problem is equivalent to a sphere packing problem, for which there should be a lot of advanced results.